# Generate Source code suing jaxb plugin in spring boot 3 and Java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, maven-3, java-17

I am trying generating source code from xsd file using jaxB file. Please check below plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/countries.xsd</source>
        </sources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Its default generated code inside of target folder.
For generating into custom package used below tags

```
<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
<packageName>com.test.generated</packageName>
```

But its not generated code under the mentioned package.

Please let me know if I missing something. Or is there any other solutions for the same